# Why does "cat /tmp/out1 > /tmp/in2 &" appear as "bash" with the "ps" command?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, ps, fifo

Consider:

```
mkfifo /tmp/out1
mkfifo /tmp/in2
cat /tmp/out1 > /tmp/in2 &
```

When I run

```
ps
```

it appears as `bash` in the `CMD` section.

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ps` lists **bash** as the running process because the bash process is blocked trying to open the fifo `/tmp/in2` before spawning the `cat` command.  Since `bash` is responsible for handling your redirect(`> /tmp/in2`), it must first open `/tmp/in2` so that it can later use the `dup2` system call to change the `STDOUT` of the `cat` command to the file descriptor for `/tmp/in2`.  Unfortunately, the call to `open` is blocking in this case.

If you were to run the command inside strace:

```
strace -f bash -c "cat /tmp/out1 > /tmp/in2"
```

you would see it stop at:

```
[pid 18457] open("/tmp/in2", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666
```

It is blocked until another process opens the file for reading.  According to the [fifo(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo) man page:

> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for each FIFO special file that is opened by at least one process. The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.
>
> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode. In this case, opening for read only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write side yet, opening for write only will fail with ENXIO (no such device or address) unless the other end has already been opened.

If you were to open `/tmp/in2` for reading first (say by adding `cat /tmp/in2 &` before your final cat command), you would see your final `cat` command show up in your process tree.